# Biggest number in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with numbers and names in the following format:

```
129308123, Some Name
12390123, Some Other Name
```

I am trying to grab the biggest number in this textfile and also read on what line it is located. I tried multiple methods but none seem to be working for me. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
file_in = open('kaartnummers.txt', 'r')
regels = len(file_in.readlines())

smallestInt = 0

intList = [int(x) for x in file_in.readlines()]


number = max(intList)
laatsteregel = ''

string_format = 'Deze file telt {0} regels\n' \
                'Het grootste kaartnummer is: {1} en dat staat op regel {2}'
result = string_format.format(regels, number, laatsteregel)
print(result)
```

Comment: You should set `smallestInt` to the highest integer possible initially or a number larger than all numbers in file.

Comment: when you call `file_in.readlines()` it reads the whole file, so calling it again returns an empty list.  So don't use `regels = len(file_in.readlines())` just do `regels = len(intList)`

Comment: Apart from TadhgMcDonald-Jensen's observation, if lines are `val, some_name`, `int(x`) will raise an error since it cannot convert it. `int(x[0])` would be more appropriate after you split the line on `,`. Also it is better to save the `int` value along with an `index` (hint: use `enumerate`). `max` can then grab the max along with the number on which it was located.

Comment: @AndrewL. I disagree, but it doesn't even matter since `smallestInt` is unused in the program.

Comment: @TrevorMerrifield Then what would you do? You would need to set the highest possible number so the smallest is accurately found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the largest number in the file, split the line with `split`

```
file_in = open('kaartnummers.txt', 'r')

smallestInt = 0

intList = [int(x.split(",")[0]) for x in file_in.readlines()]
print(intList)
regels = len(intList)
number = max(intList)
laatsteregel = ''

string_format = 'Deze file telt {0} regels\n' \
                'Het grootste kaartnummer is: {1} en dat staat op regel {2}'
result = string_format.format(regels, number, laatsteregel)
print(result)
```

**kaartnummers.txt**

```
11, Bob
22, James
33, Nick
23, Steve
25, John
21, Ken
```

Output

```
python pyprog.py 
[11, 22, 33, 23, 25, 21]
Deze file telt 6 regels
Het grootste kaartnummer is: 33 en dat staat op regel
```

To get the line number, you can use this code (remember it starts at 0)

```
print("line number " + str(intList.index(max(intList))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly